# Can i use rust instead of c++ in OS Development

Tags: rust, osdev

I want to know if rust complied code have OS dependent code in it or not.(not talking about print like stuff)

for example

```
let x  = (4i,2i,3i)
let y  = (3i,4i,4i)
```

now if compare `x == y` is it using some of its library and if yes is platform dependent.

**Edited:**
Like in C++ we should not use new, try catch, or any standard lib.
what are the things we should be avoid while writing in rust.

Comment: have a look into: http://blog.theincredibleholk.org/blog/2013/11/18/booting-to-rust/

Comment: You can use this: http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/index.html

Comment: This would also be a great resource: https://os.phil-opp.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the code that the rust compiler will generate for a snippet like that yourself, without having to even install Rust locally.

Just visit the web-based playpen, and type your snippet in there.  You can run the program (and thus observe what it does via print statements), or, more usefully in this case, you can compile the program down to the generated assembly and then inspect it to see if it has calls to underlying system routines.

If you go to this link: http://is.gd/Be6YVJ I have already put such a program into the playpen.  (See bottom of this post for the actual program text.)

If you hit the asm button, you can then see the assembly for each routine.  (I have added `inline(never)` attributes to the relevant functions to ensure that they do not get optimized away by the compiler.)

Here is the generated assembly for `bar` below, a function that calls out to a higher-order function to get a pair of 3-tuples, and then compares them for equality:

```
    .section    .text._ZN3bar20h2bb2fd5b9c9e987beaaE,"ax",@progbits
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _ZN3bar20h2bb2fd5b9c9e987beaaE,@function
_ZN3bar20h2bb2fd5b9c9e987beaaE:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmpq    %fs:112, %rsp
    ja  .LBB0_2
    movabsq $56, %r10
    movabsq $0, %r11
    callq   __morestack
    retq
.LBB0_2:
    subq    $56, %rsp
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   *%rax
    movq    8(%rsp), %rcx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    jne .LBB0_5
    movq    40(%rsp), %rcx
    cmpq    %rcx, 16(%rsp)
    jne .LBB0_5
    movq    48(%rsp), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    sete    %al
.LBB0_5:
    addq    $56, %rsp
    retq
.Ltmp1:
    .size   _ZN3bar20h2bb2fd5b9c9e987beaaE, .Ltmp1-_ZN3bar20h2bb2fd5b9c9e987beaaE
    .cfi_endproc
```

So you can see that the only thing it is calling out to is a helper routine, `__morestack`, that checks for stack-overflow (or allocate more stack, in systems with segmented stack support).  (So for an example like this, that is the only core functionality you will need to provide yourself; note that you could just have it halt the kernel.)

Here is the program I put into the playpen:

```
#[inline(never)]
fn bar(f: fn() -> ((int, int, int), (int, int, int))) -> bool {
    let (x, y) = f();
    x == y
}

#[inline(never)]
fn foo_1() -> ((int,int,int), (int,int,int)) {
    let x  = (4i,2i,3i);
    let y  = (3i,4i,4i);
    (x, y)
}

#[inline(never)]
fn foo_2() -> ((int,int,int), (int,int,int)) {
    let x  = (4i,2i,3i);
    (x, x)
}

fn main() {
    println!("bar(foo_1): {}", bar(foo_1));
    println!("bar(foo_2): {}", bar(foo_2));
}
```

Comment: Can i generate 32 bit code instead of 64 bit
i am using "rust --emit asm file.rs" but it is giving me in 64bit

Comment: We do support generating 32-bit code, but we don't distribute pre-compiled 32-bit libraries for all architectures, I think.  In particular, I do not think my Mac OS X build of rust has 32-bit libraries out-of-the-box.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at the `--target` and the various `-C` subflags, in particular `-C target-cpu=...` (all the `-C` subflags are listed if you do `rustc -C help`).

Answer (score 1):

Rust had been designed to allow one to implement an operating system kernel, drivers or an application  that does not even have an operating systems and runs on bare-metal hardware.

Currently Rust's standard runtime can be disable with `#![no_std]` attribute in the code. You can still use some libraries, such as [`libcore`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/). One of the things that you will not get without runtime is `format!` and `println!` macros, the `sprintf()` and `printf()` equivalents.

For an example of something you can do today, take a look at [Zinc project](http://zinc.rs/).